# Successful output via the Ansible ec2 module for starting an instance, but it doesn't change the state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

We're using the Ansible ec2 module to start instances in an external teams environment, and the module succeeds from the Ansible end but looking at the console it does not register any changes. We are able to successfully stop instances, but not start instances. I've tried to mimic the behavior using the AWSCLI from our AWS bastion host, and that produces the same error where the VM goes into a 'Pending' state, but does not start. We've configured the AWSCLI to use an IAM Profile for authentication vs AWS keys due to constraints from our client, we use this same configuration for our AWS Ansible modules. The profile seems like it has all the necessary permissions based on the AWS documentation. Currently it has the 'AmazonEC2FullAccess' policy as the only policy associated with our role. I would think that would be enough, if we're able to stop instances successfully via those policies, why wouldn't we be able to start? Unless there may be another permission needed? What are we doing incorrectly?

Comment: Do you have ebs volume(s) encrypted with kms?

Comment: {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "kms:CreateGrant"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kms:*:*:key/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/i-abcdefghijk"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
Can you try this policy?